# chartJS - Line Chart - DataLabels Formatting Function not working

Tags: javascript, html, flask, chart.js

I have the following HTML/JS code as follows which takes two lists:

- labels
- values

And converts it into a line chart with labels on the points:

```
<div style = "position:relative; bottom:140px; z-index: -2;">
<canvas id="lineChart" width = 600 height = 200></canvas>
<script>
    Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
    var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
    var linechart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: {{ labels | safe}},
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Data points",
                    data: {{ values | safe}},
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
                    lineTension: 0.5
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
        responsive: true,
        layout: {
            padding: {
                top: 100
                    }
                },
        scales: {
          x: {
            grid: {
              display: false
            }
          },
          y: {
            display: false,
          }
        },

        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'top',
                formatter: Math.round,
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold',
                    size: 15
                }
            }

        }
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is working fine:

[image]

However, I want the labels to have the `'£'` symbol before and `'m'` after

Every time I try to use the formatter function like:

```
formatter: function(value){
            return value + 'm';
```

Or any other combination, the chart fails to return. I am completely perplexed why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a repro of this?

Comment: I cannot share the data as it is very sensitive. Were you thinking it was a data issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `formatter` works fine for me.

```
formatter: v => '£' + v + 'm'
```

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code below.

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Data points",
      data: [567, 894, 883, 833, 710, 714, 578],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
      lineTension: 0.5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 100
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        display: false,
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        formatter: v => '£' + v + 'm',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
          size: 15
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

> If your code still doesn't work, there may be a syntax error somewhere. Try to open your browser's `DevTools` and check the console tab for any errors that help you locate the source of the problem.